# JSON response standards powered by Rails 4 app for an iOS app

Tags: api, ruby-grape

Is there any standard for JSON response for an app powered by Rails 4 with Grape gem for an iOS app?

What are the standards or typical success/failure response format an iOS developer would expect to see?

For example, look at the venues API response;

First example:

"venues":[{
"id":2,
"name":"Joes Pizza",
"city":"San Francisco",
"state":"CA",
"address":"1 Market St",
"website_url":"http://www.joepizza.com",
"food_type":"Pizza",
"venue_type":"Restaurant"
}]

This doesn't contain any response, data attributes present in the response.

Second Example,

{"response":"success","message":""}],
[{"data":[{
"id":2,
"name":"Joes Pizza",
"city":"San Francisco",
"state":"CA",
"address":"1 Market St",
"website_url":"http://www.joepizza.com",
"food_type":"Pizza",
"venue_type":"Restaurant"
}]}

This contain response, message and data attributes.

I would like to understand the better practices in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about iOS specifically, but there certainly are emerging standards for how JSON responses from APIs should be formatted.

The two popular ones I'm aware of are

- [JSON-HAL](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-kelly-json-hal-06)  (see also [the creator's original description](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html)) and
- [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org/).

The advantage of adopting one of these standards (and [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) more generally), beyond the time saved designing your own, is that there are generic, open-source libraries for clients able to consume these APIs with little or no custom programming. ([The HyperResource gem for Ruby](https://github.com/gamache/hyperresource) is one such example, which I've used in server-side code to navigate [the REST API I implemented](http://api.rideyork.ca/) with no additional configuration whatsoever.)